# Launch my application when a user opens a certain application - Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, instagram

Is there a way to open my application when a user opens a certain application?

For instance, I want to launch my application's floating button as soon as the user opens Instagram. Or even better is they open the "story" camera?

This is different from inexplicit intent, since, I don't have a way of interacting with Instagram, but is it still possible?

Do I need to check with the system to see which application are currently open or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a large security hole, if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NomadMaker says, in general this is difficult to do because it would be a security issue. In fact, an issue like this was published as the [Strandhogg vulnerability](https://promon.co/security-news/strandhogg/). That said, some apps (like LastPass) use/abuse the [AccessibilityService API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) to get this information. This would be an OK way to do this if you're making an app for yourself, but is discouraged if you plan to distribute the app.